# Why can unexpand on MacOS change internal spaces without the "-a" argument?

Tags: macos, unix, expand

The man page for `unexpand` states:

> By default, only leading blanks and tabs are reconverted to maximal strings of tabs.

However, it seems to definitely be converting internal blanks as well:

```
echo "  HELLO  THERE" | unexpand -t 2 | tr '\t' '_'
```

yields

```
_HELLO_ THERE
```

instead of the expected

```
_HELLO  THERE
```

This is the output I'd expect if I included the `-a` option, but the output is the same with or without that option.

Comment: Interesting. I'm seeing the same behavior in GNU coreutils `unexpand` (except when explicitly passing `--first-only`), so it doesn't seem to be limited to the MacOS one.

Comment: ahh! actually, this is explicitly documented in the GNU version; `-t` implies `-a`. I'm going to need to read the POSIX spec more closely to understand why this is permissible.

Comment: thanks for the edits, editors!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/unexpand.html#tag_20_142), emphasis added:

> When `-t` is specified, the presence or absence of the `-a` option shall be ignored; **conversion shall not be limited to the processing of leading `<blank>` characters.**

The GNU coreutils version of `expand` (but not the BSD one used by Apple) has a `--first-only` option which counteracts this behavior.

Comment: hm, seems like a documentation bug then. the apple docs definitely don't mention this behavior. thanks!  It does seem strange that using `-t` should obviate `-a` in posix tho.

Comment: Sometimes POSIX codifies and documents legacy behavior even when it's counterintuitive.